PHP secure storage for sensitive document uploads
I need help deciding how to securely store sensitive docs uploaded via a PHP script. I realize I'm not personally qualified for this task (if I was I wouldn't be asking this question) but need to know developer qualifications to find someone who is. We need to accept W2 (tax) forms from our sales people in the form of PDF uploads. Simple storage on a server is obviously out. I've been looking at using an AWS S3 bucket. I believe the uploads are encrypted but what exactly does that mean in terms of someone (unauthorized) getting hold of a doc from the bucket? Is the contents of the PDF still readable? They state "S3 maintains compliance programs, such as PCI-DSS, HIPAA/HITECH, FedRAMP, EU Data Protection Directive, and FISMA, to help you meet regulatory requirements."
Will an AWS S3 bucket work for this application? If not, any other suggestions?

Secure against what?
If you're afraid someone is going to pull the HD and take it home then full disk encryption works (so long as you didn't leave the key lying around).
If you're afraid someone is going to log into the server and view it there you'll need access controls.
If you're afraid someone is going to sniff packets in flight then TLS might help.
And that is in no way a complete list of concerns. I'm just trying to illustrate how security is no simple thing.

to help you meet regulatory requirements

That is worded that way so they can point at how you used it when something goes wrong. S3 is "simple storage on a server", just not yours. It will only protect you as well as you use it. Thinking you can outsource the entire security and compliance problem is fantastically dangerous.
But I'll point you to some good starting points:

NIST - Guide to Protecting the
Confidentiality of Personally
Identifiable Information (PII)

Information Security Stack Exchange


